# PHP MySql вывод товаров по категориям

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 3 таблицы.

```
catalog_categories = Содержит id, name .... (категории товаров)
products = Содержит id, name, img.... 
catalog_relations = Содержит cid, pid, type{
type{
 1 = продукт
 2 = категория
}
pid = id родительской категории
cid = id категории или товара
}
```

Тоесть таблица catalog_relations содержит связи. Причина ее наличия - товар может принадлежать нескольким категориям, так и категория может пренадлежать нескольких другим категориям. Из-за чего получается каша.

Как мне вывести максимально производительно продукты категории, чтобы я указывал id категории он сам искал категории его дочернии элементы и выводил продукты всего этого.

Не получается построить правильный sql запрос для этого

Для начала мне нужно получить список id всех дочерних элементов категории, тоесть найти все cid, у которых pid равен 0 нулю допустим, а потом рекрсивно найти у них потомков

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_relations` (
```

`cid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Дочерний элемент',
`pid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Родительский элемент',
`type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 - продукт, 2 - категории, 3 - модификации'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

### --
-- Дамп данных таблицы `catalog_relations`

INSERT INTO `catalog_relations` (`cid`, `pid`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 0, 2),
(18, 1, 2),
(19, 18, 2),
(20, 19, 2),
(21, 19, 2);

CREATE TABLE `catalog_categories` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`templates` varchar(99) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'category',
`time_creation` int(11) NOT NULL,
`active` int(11) NOT NULL,
`sort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`is_nav` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`sort_nav` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999',
`last_modified` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

### --
-- Дамп данных таблицы `catalog_categories`

INSERT INTO `catalog_categories` (`id`, `url`, `name`, `title`, `templates`, `time_creation`, `active`, `sort`, `is_nav`, `sort_nav`, `last_modified`) VALUES
(1, 'catalog', 'Каталог', 'Каталог', 'category', 1593723600, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1630052113),
(18, 'dveri-i-furnitura', 'Двери и фурнитура', 'Двери и фурнитура', 'category', 1626037200, 1, 25, 0, 0, 1636391443),
(19, 'furnitura-dvernaya', 'Фурнитура дверная', 'Фурнитура дверная', 'category', 1626037200, 1, 9999, 0, 0, 1630093856),
(20, 'dovodchiki', 'Доводчики', 'Доводчики', 'category', 1626100822, 1, 9999, 0, 0, 1626100822),
(21, 'evrocilindry', 'Евроцилиндры', 'Евроцилиндры', 'category', 1626100823, 1, 9999, 0, 0, 1626100823);

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
```

`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`prefix_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,

Comment: Точную версию MySQL нам предлагается угадать?

Comment: Словесное описание - это ни о чём. Выложите CREATE TABLE всех таблиц, пример данных (5-7-10 записей) в виде INSERT INTO, и требуемый результат для этих данных и 1-2 определённых значений критерия отбора, с пояснениями. Да - код не скриншотами (а то есть любители!), а текстом, нормально форматированным.